# Rust tokio websocket echo server, flat_map stream into multiple messages

Tags: rust, websocket, stream, rust-tokio

I'm playing with tokio websocket, I've started [from the echo example](https://github.com/snapview/tokio-tungstenite/blob/master/examples/echo-server.rs) and trying to change it.
What I'm trying to do is parsing an input message, extracting a number from it and sending back to the client the same message 'n' times.

What I did so far is:

```rust
    let (mut write, read) = ws_stream.split();
    // We should not forward messages other than text or binary.

    read.try_filter(|msg| future::ready(msg.is_text() || msg.is_binary()))
        .flat_map(|msg| {
            let msg = msg.and_then(Message::into_text);
                
            let times = msg.map(|v| extract(v.as_str()))
                .unwrap_or(0);

            let txt = msg.unwrap_or("Error".into());
            repeat(Ok(Message::Text(txt)))
                .take(times)
        })
        .forward(write)
        .await
        .expect("Failed to forward messages");
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Error: Clone` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:42:10
    |
42  |         .flat_map(|msg| {
    |          ^^^^^^^^ the trait `Clone` is not implemented for `tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::Error
```

I'm pretty new to Rust, being the Error type not owned by me, I have no idea how to solve this
Is there some different idiomatic way to write what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Below example uses a **for** loop to send multiple messages, if you find a better way feel free to open a [PR](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/rust-examples/blob/main/websocket_echo_server/src/main.rs#L24)

```rust
    while let Some(Ok(msg)) = read.next().await {
        if msg.is_text() {
            let text = msg.to_text().unwrap();
            let re = Regex::new(r"(\d+)").unwrap();
            if let Some(captures) = re.captures(text) {
                if let Ok(n) = captures[1].parse::<usize>() {
                    for _i in 0..n {
                        write.send(Message::text(text)).await.unwrap();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                println!("{text}");
                write.send(Message::Text("Invalid message:".to_string())).await.unwrap();
            }
        }
    }
```

How it looks client side
[image: echo server example]

You can see the full working example [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/rust-examples/tree/main/websocket_echo_server)